# get touchscreen working on Linux xubuntu (ncr 7443)

Tags: touchscreen, xubuntu

I took our old cash register out of the garage to see if could station in at the speakers in the living room, connected to a DAC and running spotify.
The installation of xubuntu went well except that the touchscreen is not working.
I have checked that it’s functioning by running inputattach -dump /dev/ttyS4. The terminal gets filled with information when touching the screen.

Essentially, how do i add a device from the /dev folder to the pointer devices in xinput to be able to enable it?

Comment: probably would be handy to mention what the hardware and touchscreen is....

Comment: Xubuntu is receiving input, so its nothing to do with the hardware. @JourneymanGeek

Comment: I donno man, I think its important.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek NCR 7443, it's in the title.